# How to pull in heroku postgres credential variables for nextauth

Tags: postgresql, heroku, next-auth

In the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890362/how-to-pull-in-heroku-postgres-credentials-for-next-auth#) the author is including PROCESS.ENV.API_KEY and PROCESS.ENV.POSTGRES_INSTANCE;

What are these environment variables referring to???
How do I generate this from heroku?

The relevant snippet of code from the orginal post:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
const axios = require("axios");

// Heroku api key and postgres instance
const herokuApiKey = PROCESS.ENV.API_KEY;
const herokuPostgres = PROCESS.ENV.POSTGRES_INSTANCE;
```